# Git fast forward merge is the same as a git reset --hard

Tags: git

Is this statement about git true, that a `merge` (where fast forward is possible) is basically the same as making a `git reset --hard` to HEAD of the branch to merge into?

(When merge is not fast-forward, it's clear that this statement is not true)

Comment: The effect to the branch history is the same, but a `git reset --hard` will remove any local modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as long as you do not have uncommited changes. If you have, `git reset --hard` will discard those changes, whereas a fast forward merge will not. A reset without the `--hard` argument will behave the same as a fast forward merge.

What a fast foward merge does, from [git scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---ff):

> When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch
>   pointer[...]

What `reset --hard` does (also from [git scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#_name)):

> Reset current HEAD to the specified state